# OWIN module lazy initialization based on a path

Tags: asp.net, owin, shared-hosting

.NET 4.5.x

In an ASP.NET host, is there any way to lazy install OWIN modules for specific paths instead of installing all of them in `Application_Start`?

For example, say I have low-init-cost requests at `/fast` and the main application at `/`.  I'd like if a request came in to `/fast` that it would only install the OWIN module that handles `/fast` and not the main (MVC) module that handles the root `/`.

This is a shared hosting situation so I don't have access to additional app pools.

I'm guessing it would go in `Application_BeginRequest` and be something like "check path for OWIN module, if not installed app.UseMyModuleForThisPath"

My ultimate goal is to allow these `/fast` paths to not suffer horribly during regular startup from the quickly shutting down app pools on the shared hosting.